# Phantomjscloud not working with aws lambda nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, phantomjs, aws-lambda

Feeling painful to create a AWS lambda function, I was able to deploy the same micro service easily with Google Cloud Function, when I ported the same service from GCF to lambda with some changes in handling function like context in aws lambda and deployed the .zip of the project. It started throwing an unknown error shown below. The lambda function works well in local environment,

```
{
  "errorMessage": "callback called with Error argument, but there was a problem while retrieving one or more of its message, name, and stack"
}
```

and the logs showing a syntax error in the parent script where the code begins, but there is no syntax error in the index.js which I have confirmed by running **node index.js**, any way I have attached the code snippet of index.js at the bottom

> START RequestId: 7260c7a9-0adb-11e7-b923-aff6d9a52d2d Version:
>   $LATEST Syntax error in module 'index': SyntaxError
>   END RequestId: 7260c7a9-0adb-11e7-b923-aff6d9a52d2d

I started to narrow down the piece of software that is causing the problem, I have removed all the dependencies and started including one by one and ran the lambda each time uploading the zip and finally found the culprit that caused the problem, **it is phantomjscloud that is causing the problem.**

when I include `const phantomJsCloud = require('phantomjscloud')` it is throwing out that error, even my npm_modules have phantomjscloud module included. are there any known glitches between aws lambda and phanthomjscloud, no clue how to solve this, feel free to ask any information if you feel that I have missed any thing.

Here the code that works well without including `const phantomJsCloud = require('phantomjscloud')`

```
global.async = require('async');
global.ImageHelpers = require('./services/ImageHelpers');
global.SimpleStorage = require('./services/SimpleStorage');
global.uuid = require('uuid');
global.path = require('path');

const phantomJsCloud = require('phantomjscloud')
const aadhaarController = require('./controllers/Aadhaar')
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    // TODO implement
    aadhaarController.generateAadhaarCard(event,context);
};
```

Error message from aws lambda function when phantomjscloud is included:

[image: Error message from aws lambda function when phantomjscloud is included]

Comment: Just curious: are you using Lambda to drive API requests to phantomjscloud.com?

Comment: @Vaviloff, yes I am doing that

Comment: what version of node and npm are you using?  phantomjscloud requires 6.x and I have a feeling you are using something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS uses node version 4.3 for which phantomjscloud was not supported, that is the reason it worked only with google cloud function which have a run time environment of 6.9.2, now it is fixed by the author, by any chance if you are seeing this answer you might be using some other version of node which is not supported by phantomjscloud, raising a github issue solved the problem